# how to set connection timeout for mongodb thru node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, connection, timeout

The following is the connection string and options i'm using from node.js to connect to mongodb. My web application keeps re-trying and never posts back if the mongodb server is down. Where do I set the connection timeout so I can say db server is down when it is? (The following code works perfectly when the mongo server is up).

```
(function(database) {
    var mongodb = require("mongodb");
    database.ObjectID = mongodb.ObjectID;
    var mongoUrl = "mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb";    
    var dbconn = null;
    database.getDBConn = function(next){
        if(dbconn){ next(null, dbconn); return; } //already connected: return dbconn
        mongodb.MongoClient.connect(mongoUrl, 
        {server: {socketOptions: {connectTimeoutMS: 500}}}, function(err, database){
            if(err){ next(err, null); return; } //connection fail: return error 
            dbconn = {db: database,  
                      movies: database.collection("movie") }; 
            next(null, dbconn); //connection success: return dbconn
        }); 
    } 


})(module.exports);
```

Comment: I'm still looking for help. Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html I would say use

```
    MongoClient.prototype.close
```

method to check if the connection is closed.If the connection is closed then emit a notification that the database server is down.